# What is the most efficient way to read two tables from a database?

Tags: c++, database, performance, sqlite

I'm facing a small C++ project and I was wondering what is the best way to read data from 2 tables. Im using SQLite. Can't change that.

First table has devices (150k - 300k entries). Each device has several features (5-40 features).

What is the best way to read this ? Everything is local.

I was considering:

- sequentially( each device one by one and for each one read its features.
- all devices first, then for each one its features
- chunks of devices, then for each one its features

basically would you do a breadth first or depth first approach ?

I'm no DB expert so whatever tip can help !

Thanks

Comment: I sounds like you are expected to pull all the information for one device with a single query. But only when you need the info -- searching for it is the database's job.

Comment: well im wondering which way would be faster.

Comment: Try each and measure.

Comment: yeah that's what I was planning to do. I figured there was a way which is proven to be better

Comment: Reading something 'for each' (if it means separate query) is unlikely to be faster than one big query that selects everything you actually need. If you need full list, why not just join two tables in one query?

Comment: ***basically would you do a breadth first or depth first approach*** I would let the database do its job instead of reading the data and doing database functions yourself in c++ code.

Comment: The whole point of using a relational DBMS is that YOU DON'T CHOOSE - the database optimizer chooses for you. Certainly the optimizer occassionally makes mistakes (you can override its choices with INDEXED BY). But the way to investigate such a problem is to try it out and measure the effect.